# jQuery - MaxImage 2.0 and Cycle - multiple slideshows with separate cycle options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

I have a page with two slideshows using the [MaxImage 2.0](http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/) jQuery plugin (which in turn uses [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)).

MaxImage allows you to pass options for the cycle plugin. The problem I'm having is that only the last set of cycle options takes effect. This also seems to be the case with some other MaxImage options, including 'fillElement'.

Here's my jQuery:

```
$(function () {
$('#slider-one').maximage({
    cycleOptions: {
        fx: 'fade',
        speed: 800,
        timeout: 1000,
    },
    fillElement: '#panel-one',
    backgroundSize: 'contain'
});
});

$(function () {
$('#slider-two').maximage({
   cycleOptions: {
       fx: 'fade',
       speed: 800,
       timeout: 2000,
     },
     fillElement: '#panel-two',
     backgroundSize: 'contain'
});

});
```

And everything on a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/seanhawkridge/FNgXe/1 - if you delete/comment out the second function, you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still need an answer for your question - you should run the second slideshow in a callback of the first (either onFirstImageLoaded or onImagesLoaded provided by Maximage http://blog.aaronvanderzwan.com/2012/07/maximage-2-0/#options)

```
$(function () {
$('#slider-one').maximage({
    cycleOptions: {
        fx: 'fade',
        speed: 800,
        timeout: 1000,
    },
    fillElement: '#panel-one',
    backgroundSize: 'contain',
    onImagesLoaded: function() {
        $('#slider-two').maximage({
           cycleOptions: {
               fx: 'fade',
               speed: 400,
               timeout: 2000,
             },
             fillElement: '#panel-two',
             backgroundSize: 'contain'
        });       
    }

});
});
```

Checkout http://jsfiddle.net/FNgXe/30/.

Comment: Works very well, thanks! But if I use percentages on width and height it only works on the last slider. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/FNgXe/76/

Does anyone know how to fix this and make it work on all of them? (also notice that just the last slider actually resizes the image inside the sliderbox)